kubuntu 24.04 : volume controls on keyboard stopped working
I did a clean full install of Kubuntu 24.04. Sadly I have lost volume control via my keyboard's volume keys. I can only adjust the volume from the 'settings' OS app.
minor slip-up?

You may want to report it as a bug. https://ubuntu.com/blog/the-keys-to-successful-bug-reporting

please [edit] your question with more detail about which "keyboard's volume keys" you are referring to and details about your keyboard in use and selected in the OS. You are aware of course that in Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Sound and Media you can view and customise shortcuts... On my standard English (UK) kbd I use F9,F10 & F11 as mute, lower and raise volume respectively

i have no Settings -> Keyboard in 24.04 :(

i got a Logitech K710 UK-CA that is set to 'default US-EN 104 keys' in Settings -> Input Devices, but i could find no volume related settings in that section of the Settings app either :(
